# Labelling MGLPolyLines

Tags: mapbox

I'm trying to show the names of pistes (built as poly lines). I have created MGLPolyLineFeatures using the following Swift code:

```
var pistes = [MGLShape]()
...
let shape = MGLPolylineFeature(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
shape.attributes["label"] = label // This is a dynamic label - the name of the piste
pistes.append(shape)
```

Later on, I add the pistes to my mapView:

```
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "pistes", shapes: pistes, options: nil)
style.addSource(source)
let symbolLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "pistes", source: source)
symbolLayer.text = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "{label}")
...
mapView.style.insertLayer(symbolLayer, below: style.layer(withIdentifier: "com.mapbox.annotations.points")!)
```

This code does not work - I don't see any labels on my lines. However, if I add this instead:

```
symbolLayer.text = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "Piste")
```

it works - all my lines are labelled with "Piste".

What am I doing wrong? How do I assign the name of my pistes to the MGLPolyLineFeature objects correctly? Or, how do I correctly specify the label name in the MGLSymbolStyleLayer?

Note: I am using a MGLSymbolStyleLayer because I am also showing a symbol in the middle of each piste indicating the direction of the slope - this works fine.

I am using Mapbox-iOS-SDK v 5.3

Answer (score 2):

So after much trial and error I finally figured this out.

The solution is to store the `MGLPolylineFeatures` as an array of `MGLPolylineFeatures` (not an array of `MGLShapes`).

Then use the `MGLShapeSource(identifier:features:options:)` method instead of `MGLShapeSource(identifier:shapes:options:)`.

Plus, you don't need the '{}' around the attribute's name.

The working code looks like this:

```
var pistes = [MGLPolylineFeature]()
...
let shape = MGLPolylineFeature(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
shape.attributes["label"] = label // This is a dynamic label - the name of the piste
pistes.append(shape)

...

let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "pistes", features: pistes, options: nil)
mapView.style.addSource(source)
let symbolLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "pistes", source: source)
symbolLayer.text = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "label")
...
mapView.style.insertLayer(symbolLayer, below: style.layer(withIdentifier: "com.mapbox.annotations.points")!)
```

Hey presto, the lines have unique labels based on their attribute!

Comment: If you still need the shape source to be a shape rather than features to make them easy to update, you can also group as a single MGLShape using MGLShapeCollectionFeature(shapes: features)

Comment: I was doing the same mistake, your solution saved my day. Thanks :)